RSS Feed Customization
Is there a way to customize the output from RSS feeds from website to website? Right now, when displaying an image from a story, it chooses to show an inline photo rather than a Featured Image. Of course, this causes an issue when someone decides against using images in their article. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know! Thank you!

You can modify the output of an RSS feed but only if you have access to do so.  Are you trying to get your WP RSS feed to always include a featured image?
